# SwiftUI widget suddenly comes up as blank when it was working before. Is anyone else having this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I created a SwiftUI widget that iterates through an array of strings to randomly display an image. The widget was working as normal before but doesn't seem to be working now.

Pic:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mOrpw-_vocXNHYny9J8rMbgXp7-p60Gl/view?usp=share_link
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UuW2Lj9UWiSZTPJvxa-iuUlgzEpLJU9W/view?usp=share_link

Here's the code. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
//
//  QuoteWidget.swift
//  QuoteWidget
//
//  Created by E2318556 on 27/6/2565 BE.
//

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quotes: "7")
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quotes: "7")
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 1 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, quotes: MyDataProvider.getQuotes())
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let quotes: String
}

struct QuoteWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Image(entry.quotes)
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct QuoteWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "QuoteWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            QuoteWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("WithU by Crying Cloud")
        .description("ตกแต่งหน้าจอโฮมด้วยข้อความเพิ่มกำลังใจ")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemLarge])
    }
}

struct QuoteWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QuoteWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quotes: "4"))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}

class MyDataProvider{
    static func getQuotes() -> String{
        let quotes = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110"]
        
        return quotes.randomElement()!
        
    }
}
```

I tried editing the QuoteWidget struct to use AnyView in hopes of solving some problem, but quite frankly I don't even where to start.

```
@main
struct QuoteWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "QuoteWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: QuoteTimelineProvider()) { entry in
            if entry.date < Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())! {
                AnyView(SmallQuoteWidgetView(entry: entry))
            } else {
                AnyView(LargeQuoteWidgetView(entry: entry))
            }
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Quote Widget")
        .description("Displays a random quote")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemLarge])
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried building and running your app using the widget scheme? If so, are there any warnings in the console?